# Excel copy one sheet to another workbook by using a formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm just wondering if there is a way to copy a sheet (called aaa) from a workbook (called AAA) in a in a sheet (called bbb) of a workbook (called BBB)?
The thing is that I don't want to copy and paste it by hand because I want to automatise the process since every month I want to change the file to copy (the destination file keeps the same, it is just updated).
Is there a formula for example where I can give in input the path to the file I want to copy and the name of the sheet (aaa) so that it copies and pastes it directly in my bbb sheet of my new file?

I tried A VBA code code but it says that the subscript of "Set sheettopaste = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("bbb")" is out of range.

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    Dim sheettocopy As Worksheet
    Dim sheettopaste As Worksheet
    Dim endrow As Long
    
    Set workbooktocopy = Workbooks.Open("Z:\AAA.xlsx")
    Set sheettocopy = workbooktocopy.Sheets("aaa")
    Set sheettopaste = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("bbb")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
             endrow = sheettopaste.Range("A" & sheettopaste.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
             sheettocopy.Range("A1:P250000").Copy
             sheettopaste.Activate
             sheettopaste.Range("A" & endrow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
             Application.CutCopyMode = False
             sheettocopy.Activate
             Range("A1:P250000").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Is there otherwise an other way to proceed without VBA?

Thanks in advance, it would really help me!

Comment: `Workbooks.Open("Z:\AAA.xlsx")` makes `AAA.xlsx` the ActiveWorkbook. Move `Set sheettopaste = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("bbb")` to before that .

Comment: Ok thank you. It's a very clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPaste()
    Const WBCOPY = "Z:\AAA.xlsx"
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("bbb")
    With Workbooks.Open(WBCOPY)
        Set rng = .Sheets("aaa").UsedRange
        ws.Range("A1").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count) = rng.Value2
        rng.ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the Sub you can select many files. For each file you selected prompt to input the desired sheet name. If set it empty the file is skiped and continues with next. If the sheet you wrote does not exist you are reprompted.

```
Option Explicit

'Copy this Sub in destination sheet "bbb"
Private Sub CopyPaste()
   Dim workbooktocopy As Workbook, sheettocopy As Worksheet, sheettopaste As Worksheet, endrow As Long
   Dim fn As Variant, fd As FileDialog, s As String, tmpWs As Worksheet, nextBook As Boolean, tr As Range
   Dim strinput As String
   
   Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
   With fd
      .AllowMultiSelect = True
      .Title = "Select files from disk"
      .Filters.Add "XLSX", "*.xlsx"
      .Filters.Add "XLSXM", "*.xlsxm"
      .Filters.Add "All", "*.*"
      If .Show = True Then
         If Me.FilterMode Then
            Me.ShowAllData
         End If
         
         Set sheettopaste = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("bbb")
         s = ""
         For Each fn In .SelectedItems
            Set workbooktocopy = Workbooks.Open(UCase(fn))
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            For Each tmpWs In workbooktocopy.Worksheets
               s = s & "@" & tmpWs.Name & "@" & vbCrLf
            Next
            
            nextBook = False
            Do
               strinput = InputBox("Sheets(" & workbooktocopy.Worksheets.Count & "): " & vbCrLf & s & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Write the desired sheet name without @" & vbCrLf, UCase(fn), "write the sheet name here")
               If strinput = "" Then
                  nextBook = True
                  Exit Do
               Else
                  If InStr(1, UCase(s), "@" & UCase(strinput) & "@") > 0 Then
                     Set sheettocopy = workbooktocopy.Sheets(strinput)
                     Exit Do
                  Else
                     MsgBox ("The sheet " & strinput & "does not exist!")
                  End If
               End If
            Loop
            
            If nextBook = False Then
               endrow = sheettopaste.Range("A" & sheettopaste.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
               Set tr = sheettocopy.UsedRange    '.Range("A1:P250000").Copy
               tr.Copy
               sheettopaste.Activate
               sheettopaste.Range("A" & endrow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
               Application.CutCopyMode = False
               sheettocopy.Activate
               tr.Value = ""    ' or use: tr.ClearContents
               Call workbooktocopy.Close(True)
            End If
            
         Next fn
      End If
   End With
   Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```